# Health Hazard from leaching?

Tags: chemical-engineering

I recently got dental braces and have been using foam earplugs to protect the inside of my lips from the braces. I place them between the lips and the braces and they work quiet well. However I am concerned whether harmful chemicals could potentially leach from the foam. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do.

1) DON"T PANIC  (HHGTTG)

2) Read the label on the bag the earplugs came in.  Does it say "warning: do not eat"? (no).
3) Consider: your ear is a warm, moist place. Why do you  think there would be no leaching there, even if less than in your mouth?
4) Why don't you get dental wax like everyone else who uses braces does? I'm sure your orthodontist can provide you some.

And, finally, you could look up the MSDS for the foam material online, which should allay all fears forever.

Comment: But have they got their towel with them? :)